# BASH - post array with "wget --post-data"

Tags: bash, post, wget

I need to download an xls table from a url that require two arrays as parameters.
First orderids.
Second columns.
For every order i have that columns.

```
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
        --post-data='orderids=xxxx,xxxx,xxxx&columns=x,x,x,x,x' \
     https://www.url.com/createordersexcel
```

In this way i get only first value inserted

Comment: The command looks fine, are you sure you are parsing the values correctly on the server side?

Comment: Yes you are right, now works fine. The server requested as a separator field ";" 
Sorry for the useless post.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it and thus close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wget command looks OK, and worked in a small test I did.

Your problem is probably on the server side.